# Why doesn't my way of using FileChannel, ByteBuffer and CharBuffer work like the other way?

Tags: java, nio

Given the file

```
Orange
Purple
Indigo
Pink
```

Why won't the `myWay` method in the code below give me the content of the `ByteBuffer` via the `Charset.decode`?  Notice I validate that the `ByteBuffer` has the file content, but it seems no matter what methodology I use from within `myWay`, I cannot get the generated `CharBuffer` to have the content.  The `otherWay` method works as expected. Does anyone know what's going on? I've read the javdoc for [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and [CharBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) but didn't really see anything that explains this (or I just missed it.)  What difference would it make to use `FileChannel.read` vs `FileChannel.map` if I can show the content of the buffer with `read`?

```
public class Junk {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 127;
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String fileName = "two.txt";
            myWay(fileName);
            otherWay(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void myWay(String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("I did it MY WAY!......");
        FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(fileName), StandardOpenOption.READ);
        // I tried both `allocate` and `allocateDirect`
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);
        int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
        channel.close();
        // Manually build the string from the ByteBuffer.
        // This is ONLY to validate the buffer has the content
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<bytesRead;i++){
            sb.append((char)buffer.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("manual string='"+sb+"'");

        CharBuffer charBuffer = Charset.forName(CHARSET).decode(buffer);
        // WHY FOR YOU NO HAVE THE CHARS??!!
        System.out.println("CharBuffer='" + new String(charBuffer.array()) + "'");
        System.out.println("CharBuffer='" + charBuffer.toString() + "'");
        System.out.println("........My way sucks.");
    }

    private static void otherWay(String fileName) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("The other way...");
        FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(fileName), StandardOpenOption.READ);
        ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        channel.close();
        Charset chars = Charset.forName(CHARSET);
        CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
        String str = new String(cbuf.array());
        System.out.println("str = '" + str + "'");
        System.out.println("...works.");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
I did it MY WAY!......
manual string='Orange
Purple
Indigo
Pink'
CharBuffer='������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������'
CharBuffer='������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������'
........My way sucks.
The other way...
str = 'Orange
Purple
Indigo
Pink'
...works.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple and subtle: You don't rewind your buffer.

When you call [`FileChannel#read(ByteBuffer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-), then this method will *advance* the [`position()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#position--) of the buffer:

```
System.out.println("Before "+buffer.position()); // prints 0
int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
System.out.println("After  "+buffer.position()); // prints 28
```

When you afterwards decode this into a `CharBuffer`, then you essentially decode exactly those 99 bytes that have never been written to (and that are all still `0`).

---

Just add

```
buffer.rewind(); // (or buffer.position(0))
buffer.limit(bytesRead);
```

after you have read the data from the file channel, so that the `decode` method grabs exactly the part that has received data.

Comment: I see `rewind` is on `Buffer` so I missed it in the javadoc for `ByteBuffer`.  Happens to me a lot.   It's always the simple stuff.  Thanks!